# Ebean: is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?

Tags: spring-boot, ebean

I'm useing spring-boot and Ebean, I follow the demo from github and the pom is
https://github.com/ebean-orm-examples/example-springboot/blob/master/pom.xml

domain:

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="udp_dmp_crowd")
public class Crowd extends Model{


    @Id
    Long crowd_id;

    String crowd_name;


    public String getCrowd_name() {
        return crowd_name;
    }

    public void setCrowd_name(String crowd_name) {
        this.crowd_name = crowd_name;
    }

    public Long getCrowd_id() {
        return crowd_id;
    }

    public void setCrowd_id(Long crowd_id) {
        this.crowd_id = crowd_id;
    }

}
```

service:

```
package com.ump.dmp.service;

import com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServer;
import com.ump.dmp.domain.Crowd;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CrowdService {

    @Autowired
    EbeanServer server;

    public List<Crowd> getCrowd() {
        return server.find(Crowd.class).findList();
    }

}
```

controller:

```
    @Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @Autowired
    private CrowdService crowdService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index(Model model) {

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Crowd List <<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        List<Crowd> crowdList = crowdService.getCrowd();

        for (Crowd crowd : crowdList) {
             System.out.println(crowd.getCrowd_name());
        }

        model.addAttribute("now", LocalDateTime.now());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

use command: mvn spring-boot:run to start the app, it works
but java -jar target/demo.jar it break:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.ump.dmp.domain.Crowd is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server?
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQuery(DefaultServer.java:920)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.find(DefaultServer.java:888)
at com.ump.dmp.service.CrowdService.getCrowd(CrowdService.java:21)
at com.ump.dmp.controller.WelcomeController.index(WelcomeController.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Facing the same issue here... If i manage to solve it i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

currently using Ebean with spring,

i had a similar issue and managed to solve it succesfully and the only thing i had to do was to rebuild the project.

By the way there are several steps you need to respect to work with Ebean:

- Make sure you have enabled the proper Ebean Enhancement plugin both in you IDE and in your build manager
- Make sure all the models are annotated and extend base Ebean Model
- Make sure the configuration you are using to create the Ebean server is aware of where your entity models are, and i do this by adding explicity the models package to the ServerConfig object that i use to create the Ebean server

About the last point, here is the Utils class that i use to retrieve and create the Ebean server:

```
public class EbeanServerUtils {
    public final static String MODELS_PACKAGE="com.my.package.models";
    /**
     * Create and return an Ebean Server using the configurations contained in the File
     *
     * @param name       The name of the db. This is the name followed by the key datasource in the
     *                   properties file. Ex: datasource.NAME.username=test
     *                   usually the name is db
     * @param setDefault True if this server must be setted as the default server
     * @return
     */
    public static EbeanServer getServer(final String name, File propertiesFile, boolean setDefault) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFile));
        ServerConfig config = getServerConfig(name,properties,setDefault);
        EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
        return server;
    }

    public static EbeanServer getServer(final String name, Properties properties, boolean setDefault) {
        ServerConfig config = getServerConfig(name,properties,setDefault);
        EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
        return server;
    }

    private static ServerConfig getServerConfig(final String name, Properties properties, boolean setDefault) {
        ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
        config.setName(name);
        config.loadFromProperties(properties);
        if (setDefault) {
            config.setDefaultServer(true);
            config.setRegister(true);
        }
        config.addPackage(MODELS_PACKAGE);
        return config;
    }
}
```

and here is a tipical config file for the test environment

```
datasource.default=db
ebean.db.migration.run=false
ebean.migration.run=false
ebean.db.ddl.generate=false
ebean.db.ddl.run=false


datasource.db.username=username
datasource.db.password=myusernamepwd
datasource.db.databaseUrl=jdbc:h2:tcp://testmachine:9092//path/to/test/db;MODE=DB2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TESTSCHEMANAME;
datasource.db.databaseDriver=org.h2.Driver
```

hope it helps you, 
greetings

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today and I found solution for this problem that you need to **specify your entity package** by adding the following line in `ebean.properties`

```
ebean.search.packages=your.entity.package
```

**Detail**: [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ebean/gy3imcf983o/TTJlBTnWAQAJ)

Answer (score 0):

Adding entity package in ebeans.properties resolved the issue.

```
ebean.search.packages=com.example.entities
```